# jQuery: Trigger function on custom event

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery

I've created a jQuery function called "onEnter".
It works great on the run, but I need to trigger the event whenever I want. Somethink like this:

```
$(obj).onEnter(function(){ doSomething(); });
```

That works like a charm.
Then I want to trigger:

```
$(obj).onEnter();
```

But this doesn't seems to work.
Here's is my code.
Thanks in advance.

```
$.fn.extend({
    onEnter: function(fn) {
        this.each(function() {
            new $.onEnter( this, fn );
        });
        return this;
    }
});

$.onEnter = function( obj, fn ) {
    if(typeof fn == 'function')
    {
        $(obj).keypress(function(e){
            if(e.which == 13)
            {
                e.preventDefault();
                fn(obj);
            }
        });
    };
    return;
};
```

Comment: Why are you using `new`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking to use [jQuery .trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).

So you could do something like:

```
$('#foo').bind('custom', function(event, param1, param2) 
{
  alert(param1 + "\n" + param2);
});

$('#foo').trigger('custom', ['Custom', 'Event']);
```